# Laravel Vue js Response Result not updating after axios call

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have vue component.After axios response counter not updating on popup. showInterest function is called on created method.

```
    <template>
  <span class="interested-button">
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#buyModel" @click="showInterest(idea_id, owner_id)">
      <i class="fa fa-usd" aria-hidden="true"></i> Interested to buy?
    </a>

    <div
      class="modal fade"
      id="buyModel"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="buyModelLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="ideabuy">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="buyModelLabel">How much you are willing to spend?</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          {{ sharedPriceCount }}
          <template v-if="sharedPriceCount == 0">
            <form @submit.prevent="saveIdeaPrice">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" v-model="price" class="form-control">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </template>
          <template v-else>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div class="form-group">You have already shown interest for this Idea.</div>
            </div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
import mixins from "../mixins";

export default {
  name: "buyProduct",
  mixins: [mixins],
  props: ["input_name", "idea_id", "owner_id"],
  data() {
    return {
      result: [],
      loading: false,
      price: 0,
      sharedPriceCount: 0
    };
  },
  created() {},
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    saveIdeaPrice() {
      axios
        .post("/idea-buy-price", {
          id: this.idea_id,
          owner: this.owner_id,
          price: this.price
        })
        .then(res => {
          this.loading = false;
        })
        .catch(res => (this.loading = false));
    },
    showInterest(idea_id, owner_id) {
      let _self = this;
      axios
        .get("/idea-buy-price/" + idea_id + "/" + owner_id)
        .then(
          function(response) {
            _self.result = JSON.stringify(response.data.data);
            _self.sharedPriceCount = response.data.data.length;
            console.log(_self.sharedPriceCount);
            _self.loading = false;
          }.bind(_self)
        )
        .catch(
          function(error) {
            _self.loading = false;
          }.bind(_self)
        );
    },
    updateCall() {}
  }
};
</script>
```

I am getting Array data through api call.but on popup its not working properly.I want to update this.sharedPriceCount when popup open.to show the popup content.without refreshing page.

Anyone can help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If `result` and `loading` are updated then please disregard following:

I had trouble with `this.` within function in axios call. 
Solved it by defining 
`var _self = this;`
before axios call and using `_self` within response function

Comment: Thanks for your clarification but the problem,I am checking sharedPriceCount value on popup not on same page. 

`console.log(_self.sharedPriceCount)` returns updated value but its not updating on template. every time i have to refresh the page to get the updated value.